# GCP cloud functions with "gcloud functions deploy" fails with --source as file rather than directory

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I'm trying to structure my GCP gcloud functions (in python) as a separate file per function. It sounds like from the documentation it should be supported but when I try to use --source as a file name instead of a directory it fails.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here is the command I use:

> gcloud functions deploy createAccount --runtime python38 --trigger-http --source=postgres/createAccount.py --region us-central1

and the error I get back is:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) argument `--source`: Provided path does not point to a directory

But if I put my "createAccount" python function in `main.py` inside the postgres **directory** and use this command the function deploys perfectly:

> gcloud functions deploy createAccount --runtime python38 --trigger-http --source=postgres --region us-central1

Here it loojs as though it should accept file names in the `--source` option:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-python

See this section:

[image]

Any ideas if there is a way to not make main.py one big monolith of all my cloud functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at the documentation of the gcloud command for deploying functions and the `--source` flag within:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--source

We find that it unambiguously says that it wants a directory as a parameter and not a source file.  The link you gave which seems to say that we can specify a file looks to be in error.  I think that is a mistake and it can only be a directory that is supplied with `--source`.

This would seem to imply that you can create multiple directories ... where each directory contains just the function you wish to deploy.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information.  I was thinking maybe I could do a sort of work around with main.py importing multiple other files (one for each cloud function), but so far that didn't work either.  Making a directory for every function I write feels a bit clunky to me since you have N requirements.txt files and N main.py files then.